# Verb for asking someone in a concerned tone

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word to use for when someone who cares about someone else wants to know how they are doing. The context this is in is that Person A injured themselves, and Person B, who cares for Person A, wants to know if they are O.K. (immediately after the injury).

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. From the SWR tag: "This tag is for questions seeking a single word that fits a meaning. To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead if you seek more than just a single word."

Comment: Sally called and asked after you.  OR: Sally called and wanted to know how you're doing.  OR: Sally called and asked me how the surgery went.  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Inquire after** means to ask about someone's health and in my opinion carries the connotation of concern and interest.  Although, you could *inquire after* with a false concern.  But, then you are just being a jerk.

*To inquire after:*  To ask about the health or condition of (someone).

(This is according to [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inquire+after))

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I feel that inquire might sound too formal, as the two people are very close friends and it was only a minor injury. Do you know if there are any other words that might be similar to inquire, but not as formal-sounding?